# Understand the difference between the arguments "text" and "text_target" in the bert tokenizer from the huggingface transformers library

Tags: huggingface-transformers, tokenize, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

From the transformers library by huggingface

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer
tb = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
```

`tb` is not a wordpiece tokenizer. It has arguments `text` and `text_target`. What is the difference between the two? Can you please give the functional difference as well?

The documentation says:

> text (str, List[str], List[List[str]], optional) — The sequence or batch of sequences to be encoded. Each sequence can be a string or a list of strings (pretokenized string). If the sequences are provided as list of strings (pretokenized), you must set is_split_into_words=True (to lift the ambiguity with a batch of sequences).

> text_target (str, List[str], List[List[str]], optional) — The sequence or batch of sequences to be encoded as target texts. Each sequence can be a string or a list of strings (pretokenized string). If the sequences are provided as list of strings (pretokenized), you must set is_split_into_words=True (to lift the ambiguity with a batch of sequences).

I do not understand the difference b/w the two from the descriptions above

Comment: absolutely does. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The `BertTokenizer` from Hugging Face's Transformers library takes two arguments, `text` and `text_target`, which serve different purposes in various NLP tasks.

The `text` argument is used for the input sequence that needs to be encoded, and its format can be a single string, a list of strings, or a list of lists of strings (for pretokenized inputs). For example, in tasks like question-answering, the `text` would be the *question*, while in translation, it would be the sentence in the *source language*.

On the other hand, the `text_target` argument is used for the target sequence that serves as a label or the desired output for a given input sequence. Its format can also be a single string, a list of strings, or a list of lists of strings. Back to the examples of tasks above, in question-answering, the `text_target` would be the *answer* to the question, while in translation, it would be the sentence in the *target language*.

The main difference between the two arguments lies in their intended use. In tasks without paired sequences, such as simple text classification, only the `text` argument is used. However, in tasks involving paired sequences, like question-answering or translation, both text and text_target are used to encode the input and desired output sequences. The model then learns the relationship between the two sequences.